# While trying to update to iOS 8: "This version of iPhone software(7.1.1) is the current version"

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, ios8

While trying to update to iOS 8 in iTunes i get this message:

"This version of iPhone software(7.1.1) is the current version"

My phone is registered with a developer account, And ive downloaded the right dmg for my iPhone 5:
iOS 8 beta - iPhone 5 (Model A1429) - 12A4265u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to hold down Alt and click the restore button in iTunes. Then click chose .ipsw and select your downloaded iOS 8 ipsw